# MySQL - Trouble with: create view with data from multiple tables

Tags: mysql

I'm quite new to SQL, and am having issues with creating a view, in MySQL, that utilizes data from multiple tables with varying columns.

I need the view to pull data from 5 tables, using 8 columns within those various tables.

For instance: table1 has 4 columns that I need the data from, table2 has 1 column, table3 has 1 column, and table4 has 1 column.

I've tried, poorly, to do it, but would love to have someone point me in the right direction. Is this something I will need to utilize joints for? I can't use UNION, as all tables would have to have the same number of columns, correct?

Comment: Yes, `JOIN` would be the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to use a join, something like this:

```
CREATE VIEW view1 AS 
SELECT t1.col1, t1.col2, t2.col1, t2.col2 
FROM table1 t1 
INNER JOIN ON table2 t2 on t1.col1 = t2.col2;
```

This is a very generic and pretty standard `JOIN` and `SELECT`. What I usually do is create my `SELECT` and make sure it returns what I want. Then I put the `CREATE VIEW [NAME} AS` directly in front of it, then the view is created. Now all you do is call the view like this `SELECT * FROM view1;`

One more side note, when you `JOIN` you will need to make sure the columns you are joining have data in common. Usually you `JOIN` on column `ID`. For example, `table1.ID` and the column in `table2` where `table1` column `ID` is present. But this could be any data that is unique.

See the MySQL documentation for specifics https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-view.html